# Is it possible to change the position of a Gtk.MessageDialog's caption text?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, messagedialog

I'm working on a project where I use the Gtk.MessageDialog to get user input.

Now, it *works*, but there is one thing I'd like to change, and that is where the caption text is positioned within the dialog.

Here's what it looks like right now:

[image]

I was wondering if I could move it down slightly so it looks more like this:

[image]

It's not a massive change, but I think it looks a little bit better.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the PyGTK API calls, but in C you can use

```
gtk_message_dialog_get_message_area ()
```

to get the container (box) of the messages (labels). I imagine you can then apply padding and/or margin to the container to obtain what you want to achieve.